# A question about regular sequences and system of parameters.

Tags: commutative-algebra

$(R,\mathfrak{m},k)$ is a Noetherian local ring, $M$ is a (not necessarily finite) $R$-module and $x$ is a sequence that is both a system of parameters of $R$ and $M$-regular.

I need to show that there exists $y\in M\setminus xM$ such that $\mathfrak{m}y\subset xM$.

This is supposed to follow from the observation that $\mathfrak{m}^i\subset(x)$ for large enough $i$.

Comment: Are you assuming the dimension of the ring is 1?

Comment: No. The sequence is not singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\dim R = d$ and $\underline{x} = x_1, \dots, x_d$ a system of parameters of $R$. Since $\underline{x}$ is $M$-regular, $\dim M/ \underline{x}M = 0$. The existence of $y \in M \setminus \underline{x}M$ such that $\mathfrak m y \subset xM$ is equivalent to the existence of $z \in M/ \underline{x}M$ such that $\mathfrak mz = 0$ in $M/ \underline{x}M$.

Choose any non-zero element $w \in M/ \underline{x}M$ and consider the submodule $Rw$ of $M / \underline{x}M$. This module $Rw$ is noetherian of dimension zero. So, it is of the finite length. Thus, there exists $s$ such that $\mathfrak  m^s Rw \neq 0$ but $\mathfrak m^{s+1} Rw = 0$. Then you can choose $z$ to be any element in $\mathfrak m^s Rw \setminus \mathfrak m^{s+1} Rw$.